# Relation between UICollectionView and layout object

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am new in IOS and i am trying to understand the concept of UICollectionView. I am reading some articles. All article talk about layout object. But i am not  understand the relation between UICollectionView and layout object. Please, can you help me to understand that concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UICollectionViewLayout**

> The UICollectionViewLayout class is an abstract base class that you
>   subclass and use to generate layout information for a collection view.
>   The job of a layout object is to determine the placement of cells,
>   supplementary views, and decoration views inside the collection view’s
>   bounds and to report that information to the collection view when
>   asked. The collection view then applies the provided layout
>   information to the corresponding views so that they can be presented
>   onscreen.

This is the base class for [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewFlowLayout) and [UICollectionViewTransitionLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewTransitionLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewTransitionLayout).
When initializing the `UICollectionView` you HAVE to specify which layout you want to use of the two mentioned above. If you want a normal flow layout like Instagram or basically any `UITableView`, then you choose `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. If you want it to have a specialized behavior layout like to create interactive transitions, gesture recognizers or touch events to implement behaviors when changing from one layout to another in your collection view, you take `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout`.

In code:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
// OR
UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *collectionLayout = [[UICollectionViewTransitionLayout alloc] init];

UICollectionView *myCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) collectionViewLayout:collectionLayout];
[myCollectionView setDelegate:self];
[myCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[myCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
[self.view addSubview:myCollectionView];
```

**Take note:** `.. collectionViewLayout:collectionLayout];`

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewLayout)

Comment: so, when to use layout object?

Comment: I have read that from apple document but really difficult to understand to me. Can you explain it by your own thought?

Comment: Do you want to know the difference between `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewLayout`? Or do you just want to know what is `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I want to know the difference between UICollectionView and UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: Updated the answer in my own words, hope this helps.

Comment: @bir, well, if you know HTML and CSS, UICollectionView is like HTML, while UICollectionViewLayout is quite like CSS.
Check out this Link on NSHipster: http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/

Comment: What happen, if i don't want to use  UICollectionViewFlowLayout or UICollectionViewTransitionLayout in UICollectionView @emotality

Comment: Try `UICollectionView *myCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];` and you will probably get a crash as you need to set the layout it should use, otherwise the view will be nil.